# Node.js fs.accessSync not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js

On Windows I have a shared folder with only `Read` permissions and the following code fails to detect that folder doesn't have write permissions:

```
fs.accessSync("\\\\machine1\\shared",fs.W_OK);
```

I expect it to throw exception as per the docs.

Comment: What do you mean _code fails_, what output did you get? I'm not currently in Windows but on Linux it does throws an exception.

Comment: @RahilWazir Code fails -  means it doesn't throw any exception

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug! I have logged the following issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2949

Quoting from [this comment](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2949#issuecomment-141428240):

> See [#1397](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1397) for background, it's the expected behavior insofar that it's not really possible to determine whether a folder is writable (without actually opening it) because that's controlled by the ACL, not the folder's metadata.
>
> I don't think a reliable fix is possible so I'll close this out. Trying to open the folder in write-only mode isn't reliable either, it misreports when the folder is locked.

Comment: ugh.  same problem when trying to detect if a file can be READ on a network share in Windows.  accessSync says, "it's fine, you can read it" and then my async code tries and throws an exception in the inner workings where I can't catch it.  how in the heck am I supposed to prevent this???